# Check if each non-blank line of text inside a cell ends with a date string. "(Completed mm/dd/yy)"

Tags: google-sheets

I assume this involves some REGEX work. Each separate line of text in a cell is separated by a blank line.

[Here is a copy of my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c9vBShVK_iyxOelo1Dc0THVRJtP3U0pmiPcxbrLLSJ0/edit#gid=1760186618)

[image]

Comment: Sheet is private. Allow access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

`=BYROW(C4:C,LAMBDA(in,IF(in="",,LET(_in,SPLIT(in,CHAR(10)),COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(_in,REGEXMATCH(_in,"Completed \d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}"))))=COUNTA(_in)))))`

This is essentially splitting by the newline `CHAR(10)`, filtering the values that contain `Completed mm/d/yy` and checking if the count of the filtered values is the same as the count of the unfiltered values.

Comment: Actually, your formula doesn't consider missing perenthesis or text after dates. It should mark those scenarios as false. See spreadsheet.

Comment: I see your updated answer in the sheet. If you edit your answer here, I will re-mark it as accepted answer.